# Getting rid of horizontal lines in error bars in plotCI

Tags: r, plot

I'm using plotCI function from {plotrix} package. Please see the figure below:

[image]

As you can see, error bars have two horizontal lines (one top and one bottom). Does anyone know how to get rid of those lines?

Here is a reproducible code that I borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083387/how-to-create-line-chart-with-margins-of-error-in-r/12083680#12083680):

```
require(plotrix)
y<-runif(10)
err<-runif(10)
plotCI(1:10,y,err,2*err,lwd=2,col="red",scol="blue", 
              main="Add colors to the points and error bars")
lines(1:10, y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `plotCI()` has argument `sfrac=` that determines lenght of those lines. Setting this argument to 0 will remove lines.

```
plotCI(1:10,y,err,2*err,lwd=2,col="red",scol="blue", 
       main="Add colors to the points and error bars",sfrac=0)
```

[image]